# Why doesn't the dot product give you the coefficients of the linear combination?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

So the setting is $\Bbb R^{2}$.

Let's pick two unit vectors that are linearly independent.  Say: $v_{1}= \begin{bmatrix}  \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\end{bmatrix}$ and $v_{2} = \begin{bmatrix}  \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$.

Now, let's pick another vector with length smaller than $1$, say, $a = \begin{bmatrix}  \frac{1}{2} \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$.

I've been trying to understand the dot product geometrically, and what I've read online has led me to believe that $a \cdot v_{1}$ is the scalar $c$ so that $cv_{1}$ is the "shadow" of $a$ on $v_{1}$.  Similarly, $a \cdot v_{2}$ is the scalar $d$ so that $dv_{2}$ is the "shadow" of $a$ on $v_{2}$.

If this is true, then it should be that $cv_{1} + dv_{2} = a$, right?  But this isn't the case.

We have $a \cdot v_{1} = \frac{1}{4}$ and $a \cdot v_{2} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$.  So $$cv_{1} + d v_{2} = \frac{1}{4}\begin{bmatrix}  \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\end{bmatrix} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\begin{bmatrix}  \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}  \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\end{bmatrix} \neq a.$$

This means something is wrong with my understanding about the intuition of the dot product.  I'm not sure what's wrong with it, though.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your $v_1$ and $v_2$ need to be orthonormal.  To expand on learnmore's answer, essentially, the reason you need orthogonality for this to work is that if your $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not orthogonal, then they will have a non-zero dot-product $v_1\cdot v_2$.  This means that $v_2$ carries some weight "in the direction" $v_1$.  Your intuition that $c = a\cdot v_1$ is the "amount of $a$ in the direction $v_1$" is correct - keep that intuition!  Similarly, $d=a\cdot v_2$ is the amount of $a$ in the direction of $v_2$.

*However* - since $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not perpendicular, the number $c$ has "piece" of $v_2$ in it, and the number $d$ has a "piece" of $v_1$ in it.  So, when you try to expand $a$ in the basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$, you would need an extra term to compensate for the "non-orthogonal mixing" between $v_1$ and $v_2$.

The technical details are as follows.  Since $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent, we *can* write

$$
a = \alpha v_1+\beta v_2
$$  for some scalars $\alpha, \beta$.  Now, take the dot product of $a$ with $v_1$ and expand it out:

$$
a\cdot v_1 = (\alpha v_1+\beta v_2)\cdot v_1 = \alpha v_1\cdot v_1 + \beta v_1\cdot v_2 = \alpha + \beta v_1\cdot v_2
$$ similarly, expand out $a\cdot v_2$:

$$
a\cdot v_2 = \alpha v_1\cdot v_2 + \beta 
$$

Those extra terms ($\beta v_1\cdot v_2$ and $\alpha v_1\cdot v_2$) express the non-orthogonality.  Written another way, we have

$$
\alpha = a\cdot v_1 - \beta v_1\cdot v_2
$$ and

$$
\beta = a\cdot v_2 - \alpha v_1\cdot v_2
$$ which shows clearly that the correct expansion coefficients have $a\cdot v_j$, but also another piece compensating for the non-orthogonality.  I could go on - you can use matrices and such, but hopefully this is enough to convince you.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: +1 for "$v_2$ carries some weight in the direction $v_1$".

Comment: @EthanBolker He should get +100 in my opinion.  What really sold me was the line of reasoning where: if we say $a = \alpha v_{1} + \beta v_{2}$, then $a \cdot v_{1}$ should equal $\alpha$ if my intuition is correct (which it wasn't).  But, doing the arithmetic, it's clear that $a \cdot v_{1} = \alpha$ **if and only if** $v_{1}$ is orthogonal to $v_{2}$, so in fact we get the dot product giving us the coefficients **if and only if** the two basis vectors are orthogonal.

Comment: @user46944 Can you post a bounty and award it to this answer? (I don't know the bounty rules well enough.)

Comment: @EthanBolker I could, but then I would lose precious reputation (which I am stingy with :( ).  But I accepted the answer, and he gets +10 for each upvote.  Since the answer is accepted, he will continue to get +10 for each upvote past 20 upvotes, if it gets there.

Comment: How can I write $a$ as a combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$ if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are perpendicular but not orthonormal?

Answer (score 8):

Your intuition is mostly correct, and you would probably have seen the flaws in your reasoning if you had drawn a picture like this:
[image]

We have two linearly-independent unit vectors $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$, and a third vector $\mathbf{W}$ (the green one). We want to write $\mathbf{W}$ as a linear combination of $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$. The picture shows the projections $(\mathbf{W} \cdot \mathbf{U})\mathbf{U}$ (in red) and $(\mathbf{W} \cdot \mathbf{V})\mathbf{V}$ (in blue). These are the things you call "shadows", and that's a good name. As you can see, when you add them together using the parallelogram rule, you get the black vector, which is obviously not equal to the original vector $\mathbf{W}$. In other words
$$
\mathbf{W} \ne (\mathbf{W} \cdot \mathbf{U})\mathbf{U} + (\mathbf{W} \cdot \mathbf{V})\mathbf{V}
$$
You certainly **can** write $\mathbf{W}$ in the form 
$\mathbf{W} = \alpha\mathbf{U} + \beta\mathbf{V}$, but $\alpha = \mathbf{W} \cdot \mathbf{U}$ and $\beta = \mathbf{W} \cdot \mathbf{V}$ are not the correct  coefficients unless $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ are orthogonal. And you can even calculate the coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ using dot products, as you expected. It turns out that 
$$
\mathbf{W} = (\mathbf{W} \cdot \bar{\mathbf{U}})\mathbf{U} + (\mathbf{W} \cdot \bar{\mathbf{V}})\mathbf{V}
$$
where $(\bar{\mathbf{U}}, \bar{\mathbf{V}})$ is the so-called **dual basis** of $(\mathbf{U}, \mathbf{V})$. You can learn more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_basis).

Answer (score 4):

What you are thinking is correct in terms of *orthonormal* basis:

Suppose that  $\{(e_i):i\in I\}$ is  an orthonormal basis of any vector space $V$  then any vector $x$ can be expressed as $x=\sum _{i=1}^n c_ie_i$

In order to get the $c_j;j=1,2,...n$ we can use the fact that :

$ \langle x,e_j\rangle =\langle \sum _{i=1}^n c_ie_i,e_j\rangle =\sum _{i=1}^n c_i\langle e_i,e_j\rangle=c_j;j=1,2,...,n$

Comment: Why do the vectors have to be orthogonal?  In the picture in my mind (based on the intuition described in my question) they don't have to be orthogonal...

Comment: I answered why they have to be

Comment: Your answer is suggesting that it's only true if the basis vectors are orthogonal (I understand why they need to be normal).  But why do they need to be orthogonal?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question I'm posing to you in this set of comments.  I understand the answer you've posted so far (thank you, by the way).  You've shown me that if the vectors in question are orthogonal, then the coefficients of the linear combination can be gotten by the dot product.  Now my question is: why isn't this true when the vectors aren't orthogonal?  Based on the intuition I described in my question, it seems like it should be true even if they aren't orthogonal.

Comment: otherwise you have your own counter-example

Comment: Make the questions step by step: If the basis is orthonormal can I get back the scalars :**Yes** WHY?  **proof  supplied**; If the basis is not orthonormal can I get back ;**no** -WHY *since you have your own counter example*

Comment: The point of my question is I don't understand why such a counterexample exists based on my intuition.  Something is wrong with the intuition I laid out in the question, and I would like to know what that is.

Comment: @user46944 The “shadows” are cast orthogonally. After you subtract one of these shadows from the original vector, $\mathbf v-\langle\mathbf v,\mathbf u_1\rangle\mathbf u_1$, you’re left with a vector that’s orthogonal to $\mathbf u_1$. If $\mathbf u_2$ isn’t also orthogonal to $\mathbf u_1$, there’s no way for a scalar multiple of it to equal this remainder. Try drawing two unit vectors and the orthogonal projections of some other vector onto them. You should be able to see that those projections won’t sum to the original vector unless the unit vectors are orthogonal to each other.